# In XNA 4, how can I access SpriteBatch's transformMatrix in my shader?

Tags: xna, shaders, hlsl, graphics-programming, spritebatch

I would like to use a custom effect with a regular XNA `SpriteBatch`. I have a 2D camera which computes a transform matrix, so I need my shader to take this into account.

I have put a world matrix property into my shader:

```
float4x4 World;
```

However, it does not get set by `SpriteBatch`:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(spriteSortMode, blendState, samplerState,
    depthStencilState, rasterizerState, effect, camera.WorldToScreen);
```

Everything is rendered properly if I set it manually in the draw loop:

```
effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(camera.WorldToScreen);
```

How can I set up my shader parameters to make `SpriteBatch` set them up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

That is explained here by Shawn Hargreaves, the Xna lead coder

https://shawnhargreaves.com/blog/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.html

Comment: I have looked at that post and I don't think that it is. Could you extract the relevant bit?

Answer (score 0):

In the SpriteEffect source, the world matrix is actually `float4x4 MatrixTransform`

Comment: I tried changing the shader to `float4x4 MatrixTransform; ` but no luck!